# Can controlling for a variable block the backdoor path opened by controlling for a collider?

Tags: causality, dag, causal-diagram

I have made the following model in DAGitty:

[image]

Where X2 is controlled for.

DAGitty says:

> The total effect cannot be estimated due to adjustment for an intermediate or a descendant of an intermediate.

My understanding is that I can estimate the total effect if I control also for X1, other than X2, as that would block the backdoor path opened by controlling for X2.

Question: Is it possible to find the treatment effect after controlling for X2, e.g. by closing the backdoor path by further controlling for X1?

Comment: Why would you adjust for the effect of X2?

Comment: @Firebug to understand whether I can recover the treatment effect from a theoretical point of view. It's an academic exercise.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The short answer is no - controlling for x1 in this case may mitigate bias, but does not eliminate it: the problem arises because x2 is directly caused by the outcome. You can see this in a simple simulation (Stata code)

```
clear 
set obs 1000000

gen t = rnormal()
gen x1 = rnormal() + .5*t
gen y = rnormal() + .5*t
gen x2 = rnormal() +.5*x1 + .5*y 

* .5 is the true effect of t on y 
reg y t 

* condition on x2 ~ estimate t -> y =~ .33 
reg y t x2 

* condition additionally on x1 ~ estimate t -> y =~ .4
reg y t x2 x1
```

Incidentally, Pearl discusses a similar case, where x2, instead of being caused by y, shares a common cause with y. In that case, controlling for x1 *does* enable you to obtain the correct treatment effect. See discussion of model 15 (and similar cases in models 14-17) in:
Cinelli, Forney, and Pearl (2022) A crash course in good and bad controls, Sociological Methods and Research

Having said that, it may still be possible to obtain unbiased treatment effect estimates through the use of inverse probability weighting or similar. In the current case, let's imagine that x2 is a binary dropout indicator (0 = remained in study). In this case we can weight our regression with weights = 1/p(x2 = 1 | x1, y), which you can obtain from a logistic regression of x2 on y and x1 or similar. Note that this depends on having fully observed data for y and x1 regardless of the value of x2 - if you don't observe anything when x2 == 1 then the solutions are considerably more complex or may be infeasible. See the following simulation for a demonstration:

```
* Alternative with binary x2

clear 
set obs 1000000

gen t = rnormal()
gen x1 = rnormal() + .5*t
gen y = rnormal() + .5*t
gen x2 = rbinomial(1,invlogit(x1 + y))  

* .5 is the true effect of t on y 
reg y t 

* compute inverse probability weights for x2
logit x2 y x1
predict px2, pr
gen ipwx2 = 1/px2

* Unweighted regression is biased as before
reg y t x2 

* weighted regressions with x2 as a covariate, adjusting for x1 doesn't matter either way
reg y t x2 [pweight = ipwx2]
reg y t x2 x1 [pweight = ipwx2]

* unweighted/weighted regressions with only x2 == 0 (i.e. if x2 is dropout)
* unweighted regression is biased
reg y t if x2 == 0
* weighted regression ~ unbiased
reg y t if x2 == 0 [pweight = ipwx2]
```

Comment: 1. Can you elaborate on the theoretical reason why "the problem arises because x2 is directly caused by the outcome"? You answer provides the answer per se (no), a simulation, a related but different problem, and then a solution, but I think the theoretical reason behind the phenomenon is lacking. Why controlling for x1 does not eliminate bias, from a DAG-theory point of view?

2. Can you elaborate on why controlling for x2 in the weighted regression still doesn't work, but stratifying for x2 works?

Answer (score 2):

Ok after reading your comments and thinking about for a little bit I both think, that this hypothetical scenario is kind of interesting and that I have a solution for most cases:

When you fit a linear model $Y \sim \beta_T T + \beta_{X2} X2 + \beta_0$, and most generalizations of one, you should also produce a covariance matrix of the estimates  $\hat\beta$. We can use this to calculate a coefficient from changes in $\hat\beta_{X2}$ to $\hat\beta_{T}$:

$$
b = \frac{Cov(\hat\beta_{X2}, \hat\beta_T)}{Var(\hat\beta_{X2})} = \frac{\sigma_{\hat\beta_T} \cdot Cor(\hat\beta_{X2}, \hat\beta_T))}{\sigma_{\hat\beta_{X2}}}
$$

Now a change in $\hat\beta_{X2}$, which we will call $\Delta$, will result in $b \cdot\Delta$ change in  $\hat\beta_T$. Since we know that the true $\beta_{X2} = 0$ we can use $\Delta = - \hat\beta_{X2}$ and obtain the true estimate $\hat\beta_T -b\cdot\hat\beta_{X2}$.

Let me demonstare with R

```
n <- 10000
treat <- runif(n)
Indi <- rnorm(n, mean = treat)  # true treatmet is 1 
X1 <- rnorm(n, mean = treat, sd = 0.5)
X2 <- rnorm(n, mean = 1.5*X1 + 0.5*Indi, sd = 2)
# what we we can get:
coef(lm(Indi ~ treat))
#the model
m1 <- lm(Indi ~ treat + X2)
coef(m1)
#covariance of the estimates
vcov(m1)
# correlation coefficient
bX2T <-vcov(m1)["treat", "X2"]/vcov(m1)["X2", "X2"]
# Indi ~ treat reconstructed
bX2T * (-1* coef(m1)["X2"]) + coef(m1)["treat"]
```

This is actually equivalent to fitting $X2 ~ T$ and using that to estimate and add the indirect "effect"  that $T$ has via $X2$

Comment: My question is not how to find the treatment effect. My question is whether I can find the treatment effect after controlling for X2.

Comment: Does it answer your question now?

Comment: Yes. Can you explain why "a change in $\hat\beta_{X2}$, which we will call $\Delta$, will result in $b \cdot\Delta$ change in  $\hat\beta_T$"?

Comment: Technically yes, it answers the questions, although you are exploiting the fact that we know the true coefficient for $\beta_{x_2}$ is 0, but this should be an hypothesis to test. I guess my real question was whether that happen from a theoretical point of view. I will open another question.

Comment: $b$ is the slope of a simple regression line and if your DAG represents our understanding of causality in this scenario, then we do know that the effect from $X2$ to $I$ is $0$. No matter what Fisher wrote after his retirement, lung cancer does not cause smoking.